# javaのservletのエンコードの問題です

Tags: java, html, eclipse, tomcat, servlet

サーブレットの初心者です。

今日はservletエンコードの勉強しています。

バイト列から文字列を作成する際に、文字化けの問題に遭いました。

OS : fedora28
jdk : java10
server : tomcat9
IDE : eclipse4.8

以下はソースコードです。

**servlet :**

```
package getBytes_fun;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class RequestSample2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset = UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String tmp;
        String name = "";

        tmp = request.getParameter("name");
        if (tmp == null || tmp.length() == 0) {
            name = "未制定";
        } else {
            name = decodeString(tmp);
        }

        int old;
        tmp = request.getParameter("old");
        if (tmp == null || tmp.length() == 0) {
            old = -1;
        } else {
            try {
                old = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                old = -1;
            }
        }

        String tmps[] = request.getParameterValues("food");
        String food = "";
        if (tmps != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tmps.length; i++) {
                food += decodeString(tmps[i]);
                food += "";
            }
        } else {
            food = "ありません";
        }

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        sb.append("<html>");
        sb.append("<head>");
        sb.append("<title>サンプル</title>");
        sb.append("</head>");
        sb.append("<body>");

        sb.append("<p>お名前は ");
        sb.append(name);
        sb.append(" です</p>");

        sb.append("<p>年齢は ");
        if (old == -1) {
            sb.append("未設定です</p>");
        } else {
            sb.append(old);
            sb.append(" です</p>");
        }

        sb.append("<p>好きな果物は ");
        sb.append(food);
        sb.append(" です</p>");
        sb.append("</body>");
        sb.append("</html>");

        out.println(new String(sb));

        out.close();
    }

    protected String decodeString(String str) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            byte[] byteData = str.getBytes("ISO_8859_1");
            str = new String(byteData, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return null;
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

**html file :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>アンケート調査です</p>
<form action="/ERP/RequestSample2" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>氏名</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="20" value="" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>年齢</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="5" value="" name="old"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>好きな果物</td>
            <td><select name="food" size="3" multiple>
                    <option value="りんご">りんご</option>
                    <option value="メロン">メロン</option>
                    <option value="ぶどう">ぶどう</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="送信">
</form>
```

**プリントアウト結果:**

[image: プリントアウト結果]

ご教示お願い致します。

Comment: decodeString()は必要ですか? request.getParameter()の結果をそのまま使ってなにか問題がありましたか?

Comment: コメント、ありがとうございます。
たしかに、decodeString()の問題です。request.getParameter()の結果をそのまま使ったら、文字化けはないです。
バイト列から文字列に変換する練習なので、decodeString()を削除しておきます。

Answer (score 1):

decodeString()の問題です。
decodeString()を削除したら問題なく表示できます。
解決です。